# Why did Moshe ask why the bush wouldn't burn when it did?

Tags: parashas-shemos, fire-burning

[*Sh'mos* 3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9864):2–3:

> ‏…וַיַּרְא וְהִנֵּה הַסְּנֶה בֹּעֵר בָּאֵשׁ וְהַסְּנֶה אֵינֶנּוּ אֻכָּל.‏
>   וַיֹּאמֶר מֹשֶׁה אָסֻרָה נָּא וְאֶרְאֶה אֶת הַמַּרְאֶה הַגָּדֹל הַזֶּה מַדּוּעַ לֹא יִבְעַר הַסְּנֶה.‏
>
> …He [=*Moshe*] looked, and, lo, the bush was burning/בֹּעֵר in fire, but the bush was not consumed/מְאֻכָּל.
>   And *Moshe* said, "Let me turn now and see this great sight: Why won't the bush burn/בֹּעֵר?"

Huh? The bush **was** burning/בֹּעֵר! *Moshe* should, if anything, have asked why the bush wouldn't be consumed/מְאֻכָּל.

Answer (score 12):

The Ramban writes that even though the same word is being used they have two different meanings. In the first posuk it means "burning", and in the second posuk it means "burned up and consumed". And he points out that the Targum Onkelos also translates the words differently - בער (burning) and מתוקד (burned up).

Comment: +1. I see that _Rav Saadya Gaon_ alludes to this also, in his commentary.